# Remove/Override Gridview Style in Windows 8.1 Universal app

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8.1-universal

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 Universal application. I have a gridview in my application. When I press/click an item in the gridview, I see the item with an animation or some style similar to the one which appears when we press/hold on a button. Sample image attached.

I would like to remove this style from the gridview items. Suggest me the way to a chieve this. [image]

Comment: Have you tried making SelectionMode as None. Else you might have to Edit a Template and disable the highlight on hover portion.

Comment: SelectionMode as None doesnt work. Are there no other ways than editing a template. If so, can you pls provide a sample style template that would override Pressed/Clicked style to none. Am new to XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as the style for your GridViewItem where I have commented the code for highlighting when hovered and pressed events.

```
<!-- Style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridViewItem -->
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Key="GridViewItemExpanded">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
  <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinWidth}"/>
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinHeight}"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <Storyboard>
                  <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <--<Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                </Storyboard>-->
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
               <--<Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                </Storyboard>-->
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
               <--<Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                </Storyboard>-->
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="MultiSelectDisabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="Collapsed" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiSelectSquare"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="MultiSelectEnabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiSelectSquare"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Bottom" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Top" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Right" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Direction="Left" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition To="NoReorderHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
              </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                  <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                <Storyboard>
                  <!-- These two Opacity animations are required - the FadeInThemeAnimations
                                           on the same elements animate an internal Opacity. -->
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1" />
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="1" />
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" />
                  <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" />
                  <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" />
                  <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                <Storyboard>
                  <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="DraggedPlaceholder">
                <Storyboard>
                  <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition To="NotDragging" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
              </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
          <!-- The 'Xg' text simulates the amount of space one line of text will occupy.
                            In the DataPlaceholder state, the Content is not loaded yet so we
                            approximate the size of the item using placeholder text. -->
          <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                      Text="Xg"
                      Foreground="{x:Null}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
          <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                      Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
          <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                      Opacity="0"
                      Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
          <Rectangle x:Name="BorderRectangle"
                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                      Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                      StrokeThickness="2"
                      Opacity="0"/>
          <Border x:Name="MultiSelectSquare"
                  Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}"
                  Width="20"
                  Height="20"
                  Margin="0,2,2,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  Visibility="Collapsed" >
            <FontIcon x:Name="MultiSelectCheck"
                      FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                      Glyph="&#xE73E;"
                      FontSize="16"
                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                      Opacity="0"/>
          </Border>
          <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                      Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                      StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                      StrokeDashArray="1.0, 1.0"
                      StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                      StrokeThickness="2"
                      Opacity="0"/>
          <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                      Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                      StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                      StrokeDashArray="1.0, 1.0"
                      StrokeDashOffset="0.5"
                      StrokeThickness="2"
                      Opacity="0"/>
          <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                      Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
                      Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                      FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                      FontSize="26.667"
                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                      Opacity="0"
                      TextWrapping="Wrap"
                      TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                      Margin="18,9,0,0"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```